# Is there any wifwolf in the Harry Potter universe?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts

There are examples of men afflicted with lycanthropy in the Harry Potter stories: Remus Lupin and Fenrir Greyback. What about women who transform into wolves at the sight of a full moon? **Are there any wifwolves in the Harry Potter stories or Fantastic Beasts stories?**

J K Rowling has made creative use of language in naming persons, places, and creatures. If there are any female lycanthropes in her stories, are they specifically called "wifwolves" or are they called "female werewolves"?

For context:

The word "[were](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Were)" meant "adult human male" in Old English, while the word we use now for adult human males, "[man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man)", meant any person, male or female, child or adult. From this Old English word, we get werewolf, weregild, werecat, and wererat.

"[Wif](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wife)" meant "adult human woman" in Old English. The word evolved into the modern English term, "wife", meaning specifically "married woman" rather than any woman.

Comment: Couldn't this just be 'are there any female werewolves in HP, and do they have a specific name?' Wifwolf looks like a typo - even when it's explained

Comment: Nothing has been said that would preclude it, so I suppose so.

Comment: @Adamant - Heh, if J.K. Rowling didn't write it down, it ain't canon :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**The term "wifwolves" does not occur in Potterverse.**

In Potterverse especially, unless something is *explicitly* stated **in canon**, I won't presume anything, no matter how sensible or logical the theory may seem.

In *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them*, the entry for the werewolf uses only that term: werewolf. It says that werewolves are human; it does not suggest female werewolves are called wifwolves.

> Once a month, at the full moon, the otherwise sane and normal wizard or Muggle afflicted transforms into a murderous beast.
> <sub>*Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them* - Page 83 - Scholastic Books</sub>

Comment: If JKR had intended the reader to understand that only men could become werewolves, she would have found a way to say so. There is nothing in any of the narratives to suggest that women who are bitten do not become werewolves.

Comment: @EvilSnack yes. That makes a lot of sense because not only did JKR not explicitly state that only men can become werewolves, I don't see any reason why not if the only thing required to become a werewolf is a bite.

Answer (score 8):

#### Werewolves in Harry Potter can be either gender.

While there are no named female werewolves in Harry Potter, they do exist. Fenrir Greyback’s plans to create as many werewolves as possible to use them against wizards. His goal is creating werewolves, not simply killing. Voldemort threatens to unleash him on people’s *sons and daughters*, implying that the daughters will also become werewolves.

> “You haven’t heard of him?’ Lupin’s hands closed convulsively in his lap. ‘Fenrir Greyback is, perhaps, the most savage werewolf alive today. He regards it as his mission in life to bite and to contaminate as many people as possible; he wants to create enough werewolves to overcome the wizards. Voldemort has promised him prey in return for his services. Greyback specialises in children … bite them young, he says, and raise them away from their parents, raise them to hate normal wizards. **Voldemort has threatened to unleash him upon people’s sons and daughters;** it is a threat that usually produces good results.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 16 (A Very Frosty Christmas)*</sup></sub>

The WizardingWorld.com writing on werewolves also indicates that werewolves can be female, and female werewolves are simply called werewolves.

> The monthly transformation of a werewolf is extremely painful if untreated and is usually preceded and succeeded by a few days of pallor and ill health. While in his or her wolfish form, the werewolf loses entirely its human sense of right or wrong. 
> <sub><sup>*[- Werewolves (WizardingWorld.com)](https://www.wizardingworld.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/werewolves)*</sup></sub>

Werewolves are referred to in such a way that makes it clear they can be female, but there is no term used for them that specifies their gender.

> However, any bite or scratch given by a werewolf will leave lasting scars, whether or not he or she was in a wolf’s form at the time of the attack. 
> <sub><sup>*[- Werewolves (WizardingWorld.com)](https://www.wizardingworld.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/werewolves)*</sup></sub>

Additionally, J.K. Rowling explicitly stated [over Twitter](https://twitter.com/jk_rowling/status/1044584072285052930) that werewolves can be either gender.

[image: transcription below]

> **@TibsThickTail**: So would lycanthropy be a strain/branch of maledictus or is it its own thing entirely?
>
> **@jk_rowling**: They're different conditions. Maledictuses are always women, whereas werewolves can be either sex. The Maledictus carries a blood curse from birth, which is passed down from mother to daughter.

This further implies that werewolves of both genders in the Harry Potter universe are simply called werewolves, as no term other than “werewolf” is ever used in any of these cases.

#### “Wifwolf” is never used in Harry Potter, and is furthermore not recognized as a word.

The term “wifwolf” is not used in Harry Potter, but that is likely due to its nature as an invented word rather than the lack of any female werewolves in the wizarding world. According to the Merriam-Webster dictionary, the word “[werewolf](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/werewolf)” dates back to before the 12th century. However, the term “wifwolf” is a recently invented one. It is not recognized as a word by Merriam-Webster’s dictionary.

[image]

Google’s Ngram, which can track a word’s usage in books from 1500 to 2019 at the time of writing this answer, shows no results for it, though it does show results for “werewolf” and “werwolf”.

[image]

Searching on Google produces only a few results for it, most of which are from Tumblr or Reddit, and none of them give any evidence that it is anything but a very modern invention.